# Error converting data type in a PIVOT query

Tags: sql-server

I want to convert the below data into pivot in SQL. (displaying "total" values for corresponding column "weeks" and corresponding rows "names") And while running the sp, it throws exception:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.

And

> The incorrect value "@Week1" is supplied in the PIVOT operator.

[Click here to see data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJkxo.png)

And my query is:

```
[Name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Weeks] [DATETIME] NULL,
[total] [float] NULL

@Week1 = '12/6/2015'
@Week2 = '12/13/2015'
@Week3 = '12/20/2015'
@Week4 = '12/27/2015'

SELECT Name, @Week1 AS Week1, @Week2 AS Week2, @Week3 AS Week3, @Week4 AS Week4
INTO #TempData 
FROM 
(
    SELECT Name, Weeks, total FROM #TempData2
) Data 
PIVOT
(
       SUM([total])
       FOR [Weeks] IN ([@Week1],[@Week2],[@Week3],[@Week4])
) Piv
```

I provided datatype as `datetime` for all columns, but it throws `nvarchar` to `datetime` error. I have tried with some solutions but its not working.

Thanks for your help...

Comment: To eliminate the convert error, you need to declare your @Week1, @Week2, etc variables as `datetime` and set their value using the format: `2015-12-6 00:00:00`.

Comment: I have tried this already. But it shows same error. And all parameters and variables are datetime format only.

Answer (score 2):

Using variables as column place holders in a PIVOT query doesn't work. I can produce the most of the result you are after using the following SQL query:

```
SELECT
  Name,
  [2015-12-06 00:00:00] AS '12/6/2015',
  [2015-12-13 00:00:00] AS '12/13/2015',
  [2015-12-20 00:00:00] AS '12/20/2015',
  [2015-12-27 00:00:00] AS '12/27/2015'
FROM 
(
    SELECT Name, Weeks, total 
    FROM #TempData
) Data 
PIVOT
(
       SUM([total])
       FOR [Weeks] IN ([2015-12-06 00:00:00], [2015-12-13 00:00:00], [2015-12-20 00:00:00],[2015-12-27 00:00:00])
) Piv
```

Produces the output shown below, but as you'll see the Total column isn't present.

[image: Query Result]

In order to add the `Grand Total` column, you'll need to create a derived table that sums the totals and then join to it. Something like:

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.GrandTotal
FROM
(
    SELECT
      Name,
      [2015-12-06 00:00:00] AS '12/6/2015',
      [2015-12-13 00:00:00] AS '12/13/2015',
      [2015-12-20 00:00:00] AS '12/20/2015',
      [2015-12-27 00:00:00] AS '12/27/2015'
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT Name, Weeks, total FROM #TempData
    ) Data 
    PIVOT
    (
      SUM([total])
      FOR [Weeks] IN
      (
        [2015-12-06 00:00:00], [2015-12-13 00:00:00],
        [2015-12-20 00:00:00], [2015-12-27 00:00:00]
      )
    ) Piv
) T1
JOIN
(
  SELECT Name, SUM(Total) AS GrandTotal
  FROM #TempData
  WHERE Weeks IN 
  (
    '2015-12-06 00:00:00',
    '2015-12-13 00:00:00',
    '2015-12-20 00:00:00',
    '2015-12-27 00:00:00'
  )
  GROUP BY Name
) AS T2 ON T2.Name = T1.Name
```

Result:

[image: Query with Grand Total column]

You could generalize the SQL so that you don't have to keep typing the dates in many times. In the SQL command below I've assumed that you want adjacent weeks as in your example data:

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '2015-12-06 00:00:00';
DECLARE @StartWeek int;
SELECT @StartWeek = DATEPART(WEEK, @StartDate);

SELECT Name, [0], [1], [2], [3]
FROM 
(
  SELECT
    Name,
    DATEPART(WEEK, Weeks) - @StartWeek AS WeekNumber,
    Total 
  FROM #TempData
  WHERE DATEPART(WEEK, Weeks) BETWEEN @StartWeek AND (@StartWeek + 3)
) Data 
PIVOT
(
    SUM([total])
    FOR [WeekNumber] IN ([0], [1], [2], [3])
) Piv
```

This produces the following result. Although you have lost the column headers as dates, you gain by being able to vary the date by changing a single variable.

[image: Query result]

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could accept the answer then.